# How to put a Template together with Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a template, one of those you could buy, with many css/js/images, very beautiful.

But I have to control these pages with Ruby on Rails, which I am still learning.

The template files have many directives for other files and folders.

I am trying to understand the Assets Pipeline and I am feeling that it looks not good.

There are dozens of css files, with the directives for many images that are placed in other folders.

I am very scared to be straightforward.

I am not the project owner, I just have these two requirements:

- Use this template
- Build the system in Ruby on Rails

Could someone indicate me the correct way to get along with this situation.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends,

There is a solution for dummies!

I am feeling so fool.

Inside Rails folders, there is a folder called `public`

We just have to put our css/js/images inside this folder.

For example, in my template, the `index.html` was in the same folder then a folder called `assets` which has sub folder `css`, `js`, `images`

So, the files need for `index.html` were (relatively to it) in `assets/css/...` or `assets/js/...`

Thus, all I had to do was copy my whole folder `assets` to inside the `public` directory below Ruby on Rails files.

I found it here:

[The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

I am sorry for the dummy question.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct solution to this, but may be this can help: [install_theme](http://drnicwilliams.com/2009/10/06/install-any-html-themetemplate-into-your-rails-app/) gem. I haven't used it but the link shows how to use an html/css/js theme in rails application.